# Is it possible to read Fortran formatted data in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, format, fortran

I get output files from very old Fortran programs, which look like:

```
 0.81667E+00  -0.12650E+01  -0.69389E-03
 0.94381E+00  -0.11985E+01  -0.11502E+00
 0.96064E+00  -0.11333E+01  -0.17616E+00
 0.10202E+01  -0.12435E+01  -0.93917E-01
 0.10026E+01  -0.10904E+01  -0.15108E+00
 0.90516E+00  -0.11030E+01  -0.19139E+00
 0.98624E+00  -0.11598E+01  -0.22970E+00
```

Is it possible to read this in Python and convert the numbers to "normal" floats?

Comment: What did you try?  What errors did you get when you tried it?

Comment: @Werner - This has nothing to do with fortran. This is an example of a "normal" (as normal as one can get) data file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> float('-0.69389E-03')
-0.00069388999999999996
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> line="0.81667E+00  -0.12650E+01  -0.69389E-03"
>>> map(float,line.split())
[0.81667000000000001, -1.2649999999999999, -0.00069388999999999996]
```